# tkinter keeping window on top all times on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter, window

I'm trying to create a screen "curtain" which blocks parts of the screen except for the mouse cursor's vicinity.
On windows, using `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")` keeps the window on top, even if I focus on another app, perfectly. However, upon running the code on MacOS, if the focus for the window is lost, it will not keep itself on topmost.
What would be the MacOS equivalent to `-topmost` window manager attribute which will always keep the window on top, regardless of focus?

```
import tkinter as tk

class TransparentWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    This class is just a Toplevel window.
    """
    def __init__(self, background="white", opacity=0.7):
        super(TransparentWindow, self).__init__()
        #self.master = master
        self.configure(background=background)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_attributes("-alpha", opacity)
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")
        self.lift()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    TransparentWindow() 
    root.mainloop()
```

Running this code in a High Sierra Virtual Machine resulted in the Toplevel not constantly being on top when another window is selected.

Comment: it is not my requirement. It i Stackoverflow requirement :). Shorter code is easier to test and people with MacOS can run it to confirm problem on all MacOS.

Comment: Okay all good. I edited the question with some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS using `overrideredirect(True)` disables a lot of stuff like `bind`, `Button` presses and some events, honestly I don't know why exactly. *(If anyone knows please comment)*. At least on my Mac I have this problem, I've read and seen that not all of Mac users have this problem.

So this is why `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")` is not working. But don't worry I got a workaround.

**[image: Here is your example which works exactly you want on my Mac.]**

From your code I can tell that you want a **borderless** window, here is how I do it with all bindings and event working still.

> I first put `overrideredirect(True)` then in the next line
>   `overrideredirect(False)`
>   Also you don't need `root.lift()` in this case.

Ok try this code and see if the button press normally.

**Sample**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
# root.overrideredirect(False)  # Uncomment and try again.

tk.Button(root, text="Borderless").pack()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")

# Doesn't matter if you use lift() or not with the use of root.overrideredirect(False) as well
root.lift()                     

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helped you.

---

**Here is your code which worked exactly you want *(At least on my Mac)*.**

```
import tkinter as tk

class TransparentWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    This class is just a Toplevel window.
    """
    def __init__(self, background="white", opacity=0.7):
        super(TransparentWindow, self).__init__()
        #self.master = master
        self.configure(background=background)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.overrideredirect(False)
        self.wm_attributes("-alpha", opacity)
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", "true")
        # self.lift()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    TransparentWindow() 
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow it works like a charm! One thing I'm curious about, is as far as I know, isn't `overrideredirect(False)` the default parameter for that option? Because on windows, if you call `False`, it will display the title bar, but bizarrely on MacOS it retains `True` properties?

Comment: @Dashadower The projects I worked on just needed the borderless window so I never really tried to revert the window back but I believe `update()` should do the trick but it doesn't work for me. Also there is another way to get borderless window on Mac like instead of `self.overrideredirect(False)` can use `update()` but then you have to `lift()` which I don't prefer using anyways but you can try this way as well.

Comment: We call `overrideredirect(True)` to make a window borderless. Doesn't that mean that the default value is set to `False`?

Comment: The default value is `None` [(link)](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method),  but honestly I don't see a lot of difference in None and False until unless if somebody put `if a == False` correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's very strange behavior on MacOS since if it was to work as documented, the window's borders should come back if `overrideredirect(False)` was to be called.

Comment: True, Apple doesn't much access as compared to windows.

Comment: @Dashadower Concerning `overrideredirect()` as per the [`Tcl/Tk manual`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M56): `If boolean is not specified then 1 or 0 is returned to indicate whether or not the override-redirect flag is currently set for window.`  Therefore as [Saad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10364425/saad) has mentioned, it's initial value is `None`, and you have to explicitly set it to `True` or `False`.