# Stop window jitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Have a window that sizes itself when you click and drag the mouse. The problem is the right side of the window jumps around when dragging from right to left. This issue only happens in Windows, not Linux. I'm not sure about MacOS because I don't have access to a machine that runs it. It would be good to know though!

#### UPDATE:

I have updated the code according to what `jizhihaoSAMA` suggested below and now it works fine in Windows and Linux not sure about MacOS still!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

from sys import platform


class Selector(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.geometry('0x0+0+0')
        self.overrideredirect(True)

        if platform == 'linux':
            self.wait_visibility(self)

        self.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.2)
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

        self.config(bg='#00aaff')
        self.update()
        self.lift()

        self.linespace = self.master.linespace
        self.heading_padding = parent.style.lookup('Treeview.Heading', 'padding')
        self.theme = parent.style.theme_use()
        self.style = parent.style

    def select(self, _):
        widget = self.focus_get()
        master = widget.winfo_toplevel()
        if widget == master:
            return

        padding = 0 if not isinstance(widget, ttk.Treeview) else \
            int(str(self.style.lookup('Treeview.Heading', 'padding')[0]))
        tv_padding = padding*2 if isinstance(widget, ttk.Treeview) else 0

        border_width = 3 if self.theme == 'default' else 6
        linespace = self.linespace if isinstance(widget, ttk.Treeview) else 0

        x, y = master.winfo_pointerxy()
        root_x = widget.winfo_rootx()
        root_y = widget.winfo_rooty()+linespace+tv_padding+border_width
        wdg_width = widget.winfo_width()
        wdg_height = widget.winfo_height()-linespace-tv_padding-border_width

        if x < root_x:
            x = root_x
        elif x > root_x + widget.winfo_width():
            x = root_x + wdg_width

        if y < root_y:
            y = root_y
        elif y > root_y + wdg_height:
            y = root_y + wdg_height

        origin_x = widget.origin_x if x > widget.origin_x else x
        origin_y = widget.origin_y if y > widget.origin_y else y
        self.geometry(f'{abs(x-widget.origin_x)}x{abs(y-widget.origin_y)}+{origin_x}+{origin_y}')


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.title('Selector Demo')

        font = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
        self.linespace = font.metrics('linespace')

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use('clam')
        self.style.configure('Treeview.Heading', padding=5)
        self.style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=self.linespace+7)

        self.selector = Selector(self)

        var = tk.StringVar()
        var.set(('List Item 1', 'List Item 2', 'List Item 3', 'List Item 4', 'List Item 5'))
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=var, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED, width=50, height=15)
        self.lb.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=0)

        tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
        tree.column("#0", width=120, minwidth=3, stretch=tk.NO)
        tree.column("one", width=150, minwidth=3, stretch=tk.NO)
        tree.column("two", width=80, minwidth=3)
        tree.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)

        tree.heading("#0", text="Name", anchor=tk.W)
        tree.heading("one", text="Date modified", anchor=tk.W)
        tree.heading("two", text="Type", anchor=tk.W)
        tree.heading("three", text="Size", anchor=tk.W)
        # Level 1
        folder1 = tree.insert("", 1, text="Folder 1", open=1, values=("23-Jun-17 11:05", "File folder", ""))
        tree.insert("", 2, text="text_file.txt", values=("23-Jun-17 11:25", "TXT file", "1 KB"))
        # # Level 2
        tree.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo1.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:28", "PNG file", "2.6 KB"))
        tree.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo2.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:29", "PNG file", "3.2 KB"))
        tree.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo3.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:30", "PNG file", "3.1 KB"))
        tree.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1)

        self.tb = tk.Text(self, height=10)
        self.tb.grid(pady=(0, 20), columnspan=2)
        self.tb.insert(tk.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
        self.tb.cursor = self.tb.cget('cursor')

        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.button_press)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.button_release)

    def button_press(self, event):
        wdg = event.widget
        wdg.focus_set()
        if isinstance(wdg, tk.Text):
            wdg.config(cursor='arrow')
        self.selector.geometry('0x0+0+0')
        wdg.origin_x, wdg.origin_y = wdg.winfo_pointerxy()
        self.bind('<Motion>', self.selector.select)

    def button_release(self, event):
        wdg = event.widget
        if isinstance(wdg, tk.Text) and hasattr(wdg,  'cursor'):
            wdg.config(cursor=wdg.cursor)
        self.selector.geometry('0x0+0+0')
        self.unbind('<Motion>')


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using Python `3`.

Comment: If all you want is your toplevel window to move along with the main window, then try use `dw.transient(app)`

Comment: It works fine for me. I am on windows 10.

Comment: @TheMaker I have tested it also on two system running Windows 10 and get the same results. Try left click and drag from right to left then left to right fairly fast. Do this repeatedly and you will notice the right side of the blue box jitters.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA see my response above to the "TheMaker"

Comment: I feel a little curious that what did you want to do.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Are you asking why I need the blue sizing window? It is to be overlaid on a treeview widget to select items just like in Windows Explorer. If you want to see it in action go here... https://github.com/unodan/TkInter-Treeview-Example-Demo/blob/master/treeview_demo.py

Comment: Remove the line ``dw.wait_visibility(app)``.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thank you very much, that fixed the problem. But now the blue window is no longer transparent.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Now the blue window is no longer transparent, I need the blue window to be transparent. I don't think you can use any other widget like a frame or canvas because they don't support transparency.

Comment: This ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPP7Z.png

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Yes that's the box, when I remove the line "dw.wait_visibility(app)" then that window/box is no longer transparent.

Comment: What?...the window `dw` is transparent on my PC after I remove `dw.wait_visibility(app)`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Sorry I use Linux and didn't think to test Windows. Yes it works perfect now in Windows. I will just need to detect the OS and if in Linux then I run the command, "dw.wait_visibility(app)". I wonder if MaxOS needs that command I would think it would because it's Linux based. If someone could let me know that would be nice.

Comment: A suggestion.You make the drag function complex.It could be reduce to only 5 lines.

Comment: @DanielHuckson: On mac `dw.wait_visibility(app)` is not required. Also if you use `dw.overrideredirect(True)` then you have to use `dw.overrideredirect(False)` or `dw.lift()`  to make the window visible without borders, as on mac just using `dw.overrideredirect(True)` will hide the window. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55873471/10364425) to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Saad, Thank you. I have updated the code above to reflect your suggestion above. Does that work?

Comment: @DanielHuckson: You should put `dw.lift()` after you set the window *topmost*, so put `dw.lift()` after `dw.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)` also `dw.update()` the window. It should be in this order  `dw.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)`, `dw.update()`, `dw.lift()`. I checked it and this works fine.

Comment: @Saad, Thanks once again. I have updated the code above to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA What are those five line... :)

Comment: I reconstructed your code before this.Your `dw` could also be put in `class App()`.The five lines  is to get the value of `geometry()`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Thanks for the feed back I updated the code does it look better, any more suggestions?

Comment: You couldn't also put the `button_release` and `button_press` in `class App()`.BTW,My five lines code seems hard to understand.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Thanks for the feed back once again. I updated the code again and it is  much better works just how I needed to. It's much better code now!

Comment: I just tested the code on macOS and it does not have any issues

Comment: @Siddharth Dushantha, Thank you for testing it for me, that's great to know!